# Issue with disabling protocols in java.security file

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jetty-9, tls1.3

I have springboot application deployed on jetty server and running on java 8. I want to force my application to use TLSv1.3 only. For this in the java.security file of jre I disabled all protocols except TLSv1.3 with below property:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, 3DES_EDE_CBC, DESede, \
    EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC, RC4_40, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
```

When I tried to start jetty, it gave me below error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "No appropriate protocol, may be no appropriate cipher suite specified or protocols are deactivated". ClientConnectionId:de77b523-984a-4700-a19b-ccfd0407dfb4
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1748)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1704)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1401)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1068)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:904)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:451)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
```

**I am not using secure connection to DB.** Below is application.properties file entry for DB:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://172.20.186.175:1433;Databasename=DB_Jan_2023_new;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password={ENC}ACED0005740003414553757200025B42ACF317F8060854E0020000787000000008E3425FF8F9E058D0737200116A6176612E6C616E672E496E746567657212E2A0A4F781873802000149000576616C7565787200106A6176612E6C616E672E4E756D62657286AC951D0B94E08B0200007870000008007571007E000100000010B2E212D690ECC67BC4663C4DFEE3542C74000456322E30
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

- Q1. I am not sure why it is giving this error though I am not using secure connection.
- Q2. Also, is this the right way to move application to TLSv1.3 or there are some more steps ?
- Q3. How can I check if my application moved to TLSv1.3 ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? As far as I'm aware, only SQL Server 2022 on Windows supports TLS 1.3 at this time.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server TDS protocol version 8 is required for TLS 1.3 per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/tds-8-and-tls-1-3). TDS 8 was introduced with SQL Server 2022 and is not available in other versions. Furthermore, only the latest ODBC and OLEDB client drivers have added support for TDS 8 as of this writing. TLS 1.3 not yet available with the Microsoft JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks for that info. But my concern is that I am not using secure DB connection just normal comnection. Still it uses tls ?

Comment: @Sahil, the client driver and SQL Server negotiate the highest TLS version supported by both. As a safeguard, specify `Encrypt=true` in the connection string to fail the connection if encryption is not available.  `Encrypt=strict` is also available with the latest JDBC driver in order to support TLS 8 and TLS 1.3 but I don't know if it's been fully implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks so much for that info. That helps. Also can u help answer my Question 2 and Question 3 ?